# How many chunks do I need to keep loaded to keep quarries working in Buildcraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft

In my SMP world I have large Buildcraft quarries operating and I wish to ensure that they keep on operating even when I'm not around.  I know that I can use the [Teleport Tether](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Teleport_Tether) to keep chunks loaded, however I'm not sure how many chunks I need to keep loaded in order for my quarry to continue operating.

Do I need to keep all chunks containing the quarry loaded, or do I only need to keep the chunk containing the quarry block itself loaded?  Also if I am piping items back from the quarry will anything bad happen if the chunks containing those items are not loaded?

Comment: You can also use a [World Anchor](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/World_Anchor) to keep a larger area loaded.

Comment: Another possibility is using the very similar [Dimension Anchor](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Dimension_Anchor).

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep all chunks that are actively being quarried loaded or Bad Things<sup>tm</sup> will happen. As for piping, nothing bad should happen if you don't keep all your piping loaded, however keep in mind that things won't move through unloaded pipes either so you won't get your materials till you go near the pipeline.

Comment: you just need to have the place loaded where the items get piped to :D

Comment: I once forgot to put a world anchor on the room my quarry piped to. Everything fell out of the pipe at the point where it reached the unloaded segment. I came back to a game-lagging pile of thousands of cobble on the floor.

Answer (score 0):

Just stick em' all over the place. Teleport Tethers are cheap anyways.

Maybe... Well if the server doesn't want them you wouldn't be able to craft/place. Otherwise go mad! Do you care more about the server or your quarrys?!?!

By not cheap do you mean in server RAM or resources?

Comment: Keeping chunks loaded is *not* cheap. This is a good way to get banned from a Tekkit server. :)

Comment: There is a per-player limit on the number of chunks that can be kept loaded (default 81), because it sucks up server resources. Going over this limit by scattering anchors/tethers everywhere has two effects: 1) makes some of them randomly not work, defeating their purpose; 2) demonstrates to the admin that a player is a clueless resource hog that shouldn't be trusted to not build a machine that will crash the server.

Comment: Also, please use comments instead of editing your answer. (You can always comment on your own posts, regardless of rep.)

Comment: Oh thx! So is this limit of 81 come with the tekkit server or on a plugin/bukkit?

Comment: I just looked it up to see how to change it and I'm not quite right: that's just the limit of the [Dimensional Anchor](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Dimensional_Anchor) (and can be changed with its GUI). So Tekkit doesn't have a built-in limit AFAIK, so indiscriminate use of Tethers can give the admin serious sadface.

Comment: With 1.3.2, all chunkloaders have a central config such as @SevenSidedDie suggested. There's large default, but admins can configure it however they like.